# Alert dialog appears after logging in

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog

My loging async task does the login process, it takes the user input, send it via webservices, verify it, and sends a session id if the user login detail was correct, and returns nothing and also an error if the user login details were wrong, I'm trying to show an alert dialog if the user login details were wrong, my logic is to have an IF statement in onPostExecute that checks if session id field is null or not, if null, it shows an alert dialog and prevent the user from logging in, THIS WORKS, however my issue is that even when the user enters the right detail, it shows the alert dialog box very quickly(flashes), and then directs me to the dashboard, I don't want that alert dialog to show even if it was for seconds, I think that it doesn't ready my IF statement

Thats my Login.java

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_login); 
        LB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);
        LB.setOnClickListener(this); 



    }

 public void onClick(View view){

     switch (view.getId()){


      case R.id.loginbutton: //When login button is clicked
      new LongOperation().execute(""); //Starts the method called LongOperation

      break;


     }
    }


    public class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{ //string, void, string was added automatically

         @Override
         protected void onPreExecute() {

             super.onPreExecute();
             pdia = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
             pdia.setMessage("Loading...");
             pdia.show();   

                }   

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
        Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
              SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 
              usersusername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editusername); 
              userspassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editpassword); 

              String user_Name = usersusername.getText().toString(); 
              String user_Password = userspassword.getText().toString();


              editor.putString("username",user_Name); 
              editor.commit();

              PropertyInfo unameProp =new PropertyInfo();
              unameProp.setName("userName");//Define the variable name in the web service method
              unameProp.setValue(user_Name);//set value for userName variable
              unameProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
              request.addProperty("username",user_Name);//Pass properties to the variable
      //Using this to add parameters "username" grabbed from WSDL

              PropertyInfo passwordProp =new PropertyInfo();
              passwordProp.setName("password");
              passwordProp.setValue(user_Password);
              passwordProp.setType(String.class);
              request.addProperty(passwordProp);

      SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); // Declare the version of the soap request
      envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

      try {
        HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);


        aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);  


        SoapPrimitive result =(SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
        String SessionID= result.toString();


        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(SessionID))
               {
                  Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this,Dashboard.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
               }

      }
      catch (Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
      }



    return null; 
    }







    @Override

    protected void onPostExecute(String Something) {

        pdia.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(Something);
         if(usersusername.getText().length()==0) {
             usersusername.setError("Please enter your username");
           }
           if(userspassword.getText().length()==0) {
             userspassword.setError("Please enter your password");
           }

    if(Something == null) {


    Builder builder = new Builder(Login.this);
    builder.setMessage("Invalid login details");
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok_button, null);
              builder.create().show();

                  // show dialog and prepare the fields for retry 


               }


          }  



      } 


     }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your webservice create a checker, like an integer success where if its 1 it successfully queried but if 0 it didn't query. Retrieve it in your asynctask then check in post execute if success == 1 go to dashboard if success == 0 call dialog.

Btw try using the new android Volley for networking as AsyncTask is prone to memory leaks. Cheers! :)

Comment: how can I create a checker?

Comment: hmm it depends, I dont know exactly the process with soap but if you switch to a PHP API that sends JSON I can help you with that...